# PHP: Редирект после отображения страницы

Tags: php

Как известно, функция `header` должна быть использована только до того, как содержимое страницы сгенерировано. А что если нужно после? Есть что-нибудь лучше смеси в JavaScript типа

```
echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href = "index.php"</script>';
```

Answer (score 5):

Не забываем про тег (который размещается в `<head>`)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

где `5` - количество секунд, через которое браузер сделает переход на адрес указанный после `url=`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Answer (score 2):

Лучшим будет **отложенный вывод** `ob_start()` и т.д.

http://vk-book.ru/redirekt-v-php-pri-uzhe-zadannyx-zagolovkax/